# Mikado loop trough data

Tags: javascript, html, templates, handlebars.js, mustache

I'm trying to implement [Mikado template engine](https://github.com/nextapps-de/mikado) in my website, having already implemented [Mustache.js](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js), I was expecting a very straightforward transition, since Mikado seams to be based on it, but I'm missing how to loop trough nested array in the data.

With [Mustache.js](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js), is it possible to do in this way:

```
{{# data.textuals_section.textuals}}
    {{textual_h}}
{{/ data.textuals_section.textuals}}
```

Or in [Handlebars.js](https://handlebarsjs.com/), should be something like this (never tried):

```
{{#each data.textuals_section.textuals}}
    {{textual_h}}
{{/each}}
```

In Mikado, of course is not, since `{{# }}` is reserved to pass HTML markup, and the docs seams to refers only a single level arrays, so I can't understand how to make loops with Mikado,

More than this, in Mikado the nested array seams even not accessible with the following sintax

```
{{data.textuals_section.textuals.textual_h}}
```

I've setup a little [codepen](https://codepen.io/drypatrick/pen/oNYwKBj), if someone would like to suggest a solution.

Many thanks, bey!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create a new template and add each row.

html

```
<div id="root"></div>
<template id="subtext">
  <div>
    <h3>{{data.textual_h}}</h3>
    <h4>{{data.textual_sh}}</h4>
    <p>{{data.textual_p}}</p>
  </div>
</template>
<template id="basic">
  <div>
    <h1>{{data.textuals_section.textuals_h}}</h1> 
    <h2>{{data.textuals_section.textuals_sh}}</h2>
    <p>{{data.textuals_section.textuals_p}}</p>
    <div id="textuals"></div>
  </div>
</template>
```

javascript

```
const root = document.getElementById("root");
const template = Mikado.compile("basic");
const view = Mikado(root, template);
const data = [{
  textuals_section: {
    textuals_h: "A main headers",
    textuals_sh: "A main sub-headers",
    textuals_p: "A main pragraph...",
    textuals: [{
        textual_h: "A nested header1",
        textual_sh: "A nested sub-header",
        textual_p: "A nested paragraph..."
      },
      {
        textual_h: "A nested header2",
        textual_sh: "A nested sub-header",
        textual_p: "A nested paragraph..."
      },
      {
        textual_h: "A nested header3",
        textual_sh: "A nested sub-header",
        textual_p: "A nested paragraph..."
      }
    ]
  }
}];

view.render(data);

const root2 = document.getElementById("textuals");
const template2 = Mikado.compile("subtext");
const view2 = Mikado(root2, template2);

data[0].textuals_section.textuals.forEach(row => view2.add(row))
view2.render();
```